# operator - undefined for argument types double[]

Tags: java, matrix, normalization, jama

I am working on a project which deals with large matrices of data. When i try to normalize it for my computation, I get the error

```
operator - is undefined for argument types double[]
```

my code is as follows:

```
import Jama.*;

public static Matrix normalize(Matrix ip_matrix, double[][] min_bound, double[][] max_bound)
{
    Matrix mat = ip_matrix.transpose();
    double[][] mat1 = mat.getArray(); // getting matrix as an array to perfom the computation.
    int nb_input = mat1[0].length;
    double[][] norm = new double[mat1[0].length][mat1[1].length]; // Initialize a default array to store the output, in the required dimension.

    for (int i = 0; i <= nb_input; i++)
    {
        norm[i] = (mat1[i] - min_bound[i] / (max_bound[i] - min_bound[i])); //The line where i get the error.

    }
    norm = norm.getMatrix();
    return norm;
    }
```

I am basically a python programmer and the same logic works fine in my python codes. I use numpy in python. and am using JAMA library in java for the same.

I am just a beginner in java, so please any guidance would be highly aprreciated.

Comment: `mat1[i]` aswell as the other variables are defined as `double[]`, you can´t do math with the whole array, just with a single value of it.

Comment: i am using eclipse IDE and the part of the error is in max_bound[i] - min_bound[i]. that is where the IDE underlines as an error.

Comment: is there a way to rectify it? may be i am initializing things wrong??

Comment: You are having a two dimensional array. If you access the variables in the first dimension as you do it with `norm[i]` then you are basicly accessing an `double[]`, which you can´t perform addition or subtraction with. Imagine it beeing as a excel sheet, one dimension represents the columns, and the other the rows. In order to make it work you would need to have two for loops to acces each element in each dimension.

Comment: oh.. i get it. but how else would i define an array?? sorry if i am being stupid. but i am really new to these linear algebra thing in java and if you could correct my code, i would really appreciate it..

Comment: oh okay... now i am beginning to understand the error... thanks a lot @KevinEsche

Comment: each `[]` represents a dimension, if you would want to have a an array which would be used like a simple `List` then you could just write `double[] array`. Each additional `[]` behind it would represent another dimension. Note that accessing an array element at dimension `n`, by providing n brackets, will allways return an array of the dimension `n-1`.

Comment: it worked.. thank. big time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a 2D array aka a matrix. In Java, there isn't really 2D arrays. What you are doing here is creating an array of arrays of `double`s.

So when you use the `[]` operator to access the array, you are actually getting a 1D array of `double`s. When you use `[][]` to access it, you get a `double`. So that's why you get the error. You use a single `[]` to access it and you do subtraction on them.